# Prefer std::string in std::variant<bool, std::string> for const char *

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17, implicit-conversion, variant

Consider the following code -

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int p(std::variant<bool, std::string> v) {
    return v.index();
}

int main() {
    return p("ad");
}
```

instead of choosing `std::string`, p will be instantiated with variant containing `bool` (I want `std::string`), well this can be fixed using explicitly specifying `std::string` but that is too much work , I tried providing different overloads but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such code:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int p(std::variant<bool, std::string> v) {
    return v.index();
}

template<size_t N>
int p(const char (&s)[N]) {
    return p(std::string(s));
}

int main() {
    return p("ad");
}
```

returns `1`.

Comment: It works for arrays but not `const char*`: https://godbolt.org/z/J3LJ6F

Comment: So just `int p(const char *s) {
    return p(std::string(s));
}`.

Comment: If you make the answer like that, you've got my vote.

Answer (score 7):

This has been fixed in C++20. See [P0608](https://wg21.link/p0608r3) for a discussion of this exact case.

Comment: Is there a feature test macro for this? I can't find any at cppreference.com or the C++20 standard draft. The `__cpp_­lib_­variant` macros is still stuck at `201606L` according to https://eel.is/c++draft/version.syn#header:%3cversion%3e

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [string literal suffix `s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to create an `std::string` object directly

```
return p("ad"s);
```

If the suffix isn't available then you need to add `using namespace std::literals`, `using namespace std::string_literals` or `using namespace std::literals::string_literals`

That said, I've tried your code on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) and `p("ad")` returns 1 for me

Comment: actually, in "real" code, I'm using QString and also std::variant has other members as well

Comment: but regardless of your members, `"ad"s` will work to initialize the value to std::string

Comment: @bluedragon QT has a [`QStringLiteral()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) macro to create a `QString` from a string literal without making a copy of its data: `return p(QStringLiteral(u"ad"));`